# GROUP BY after CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table from a join and summing some fields based on id. This part is working great. I am also trying to add an additional column and using a case when statement I want to populate it.

Here is the script

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
AS
  SELECT ID, IDC, SUM(AMOUNT) PRICE, SUM(COST) COST, SUM(AMOUNT-COST) PROFIT,
  CASE PROFIT
    WHEN PROFIT < 1000 THEN 'Low'
    WHEN PROFIT < 5000 THEN 'Medium'
    ELSE 'High'
  END AS PROFITLEVEL  
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT ID, IDC, AMOUNT, COST
    FROM ORDER_ITEMS 
    LEFT JOIN ORDERS 
    ON ID = IDC)
  GROUP BY ID, IDC;
```

This however returns a ORA-00905 : Missing keyword error.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Invalid CASE syntax. (Amongst others...) Do `case when...`. But you can't use that column alias PROFIT there anyway...

Comment: Question to the dufus who marked this for closing as "due to a typo or a problem that cannot be reproduced" - What typo? How can the problem not be reproduced? (Just asking the world, since that dufus is very unlikely to even remember marking the question for closing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `CASE` in a wrong way; besides, you try to use the alias `PROFIT` at the same level you define it.

You need to edit you `CASE` and use the expression that gives the `PROFIT` instead of the alias `PROFIT`:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 AS
      SELECT ID,
             IDC,
             SUM(AMOUNT) PRICE,
             SUM(COST) COST,
             SUM(AMOUNT - COST) PROFIT,
             CASE 
                WHEN SUM(AMOUNT - COST) < 1000 THEN 'Low'
                WHEN SUM(AMOUNT - COST) < 5000 THEN 'Medium'
                ELSE 'High'
             END AS PROFITLEVEL
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID,
                              IDC,
                              AMOUNT,
                              COST
                FROM ORDER_ITEMS LEFT JOIN ORDERS ON ID = IDC)
    GROUP BY ID, IDC;
```

The way you tried to use the `CASE` is useful if you need to check single values; for example:

```
select level,
       case level
         when 1 then 'one'
         when 2 then 'two'
         else 'other'
       end
from dual
connect by level <=3
```

Comment: That works. Didn't know I cant use aliases in the same level I define them. But I don't understand what is the difference between `case when` and `case profit when`?

Comment: Just added a small example

Comment: Oh I get. Thanks for the help